# Can a CAP Form 5 flight evaluation be used as the flight portion of a flight review?

Tags: faa-regulations

I recently completed successfully a Civil Air Patrol Form 5 flight evaluation.  I was told that the Form 5 satisfied the flight portion of the Flight Review.  If true, which additional seminars do I need to complete?

Comment: You should have asked your CAP CFI do complete the ground portion as well.  Normally they do.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! I reworded your question a little because I *think* you're asking if it's true that your Form 5 is valid for the flight portion of your flight review. If that isn't accurate then you can simply edit again or roll back my change.

Answer (score 1):

A flight review consists of both a ground portion and a flight portion. You just need a CFI to sign off on the ground training for the flight review.

Alternatively, you could sign up for the FAA Safety Team WINGS program. You get three Flight Activity credits for the above mentioned CAP evaluation. You can earn another three Knowledge Activity credits a number of different ways of your choice. With the three Flight Activity credits and three Knowledge Activity credits, you will complete one phase of the FAASTeam WINGS program. Completing a phase counts as a flight review